# Adding column values from multiple different files

Tags: bash, awk

I have ~100 files and I would like to do an arithmetical operation (e.g. sum them up) on the second column of the files, such that I add the value of first row of one file to the first row value of second file and so on for all rows of column 2 in each file.

In my actual files I have ~30 000 rows so any kind of manual manipulation with the rows is not possible.

fileA

```
1   1  
2   100  
3   1000  
4   15000
```

fileB

```
1   7  
2   500  
3   6000    
4   20000
```

fileC

```
1   4  
2   300  
3   8000    
4   70000
```

output:

```
1   12  
2   900  
3   15000  
4   105000
```

I used this and ran it as:  `script.sh listofnames.txt` (All the files have the same name but they are in different directories so I was referring to them with `$line` to the file with the list of directories names). This gives me a syntax error and I am looking for a way to define the "sum" otherwise.

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    awk '{"'$sum'"+=$3; print $1,$2,"'$sum'"}' ../$line/file.txt >> output.txt
    echo $sum
done < "$1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ paste fileA fileB fileC | awk '{sum=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) sum+=$i; print $1, sum}'
1 12
2 900
3 15000
4 105000
```

or if you wanted to do it all in awk:

```
$ awk '{key[FNR]=$1; sum[FNR]+=$2} END{for (i=1; i<=FNR;i++) print key[i], sum[i]}' fileA fileB fileC
1 12
2 900
3 15000
4 105000
```

If you have a list of directories in a file named "foo" and every file you're interested in in every directory is named "bar" then you can do:

```
IFS=$'\n' files=( $(awk '{print $0 "/bar"}' foo) )
cmd "${files[@]}"
```

where `cmd` is awk or paste or anything else you want to run on those files. Look:

```
$ cat foo
abc
def
ghi klm

$ IFS=$'\n' files=( $(awk '{print $0 "/bar"}' foo) )

$ awk 'BEGIN{ for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++) print "<" ARGV[i] ">"; exit}' "${files[@]}"
<abc/bar>
<def/bar>
<ghi klm/bar>
```

So if your files are all named `file.txt` and your directory names are stored in `listofnames.txt` then your script would be:

```
IFS=$'\n' files=( $(awk '{print $0 "/file.txt"}' listofnames.txt) )
```

followed by whichever of these you prefer:

```
paste "${files[@]}" | awk '{sum=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) sum+=$i; print $1, sum}'

awk '{key[FNR]=$1; sum[FNR]+=$2} END{for (i=1; i<=FNR;i++) print key[i], sum[i]}' "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: I have over a hundred files (with irregular string names,not just numbers) so writing fileA fileB fileC at the end is not really feasible. Can that part be scripted somehow?

Comment: If there's nothing else in  your directory then `awk '...' file*` is all you need.

Comment: They are all in separate directories and I usually used a file for referencing to those directories so I don't know how to apply it to this solution

Comment: That's a completely different question to the one you asked. Can you cd to the directory under which you files exist and do `awk '...' */file.txt` or use `find` to find them? If not - how do you provide them to your script today and why can't you just do that again?

Comment: I provided them to the script with the first line of the script I've written in the question, with _read -r line_ . They are each in a separate directory so I need to refer to each of the 100  directories.

Comment: I added an update describing how to do what I think it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes that is what I was trying to do. The paste solution gives some strange numbers, but the awk solution is working fine.

Comment: Is it possible you don't have the same number of lines in each file? If the number of lines or the key (first field) values vary across your input files - should the summation be performed on the line number or the value of the key (first) field on each line?

Comment: The number of lines is the same in each file, but I do have two more columns in each file ($3 and $4)

Comment: Yup that'll do it. Obviously you should have included that info in your question and made your sample input look like your real input. It's an easy fix of course - just change `+=2` to `+=4` in the awk script.